# How to enable gradient flow in scatter_update?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient

I am trying to compute the local variance map of an image by taking data from all possible window of fixed-size (eg 5x5), inside a training loop. To vectorize this operation I am thinking about expanding the original image with an operation similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PR0Bv.jpg) using `scatter_update/scatter_nd_update` inside the training loop. What this operation  essentially does is to map each element in the original tensor to potentially many locations in the new tensor, and the locations are computed inside the training loop.

However, `scatter_update` does not allow gradient propagation, and my attempt at creating a simple custom gradient for the `scatter_update` did not work.

```
@tf.RegisterGradient("CustomGrad")
def _clip_grad(unused_op, grad):
  return tf.constant(5., dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1)) # tf.clip_by_value(grad, -0.1, 0.1)

x = tf.Variable([3.0], dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.get_variable('y', shape=(1), dtype=tf.float32)

g = tf.get_default_graph()
with g.gradient_override_map({"ScatterNdUpdate1": "CustomGrad"}):
    output = tf.scatter_nd_update(y, [[0]], x, name="ScatterNdUpdate1")
grad_custom = tf.gradients(output, y)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(grad_custom)
```

Running the code above shows that `grad_custom` contains `None`. Does any one have any idea of how to properly implement a local variance map that can be used in the training loop? Solving the gradient problem would also help me with another problem I am having.

Comment: That is because [`tf.scatter_update`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_update) is an operation that updates a variable, not "pure" tensor operation. If you don't actually need the variable to keep its value between runs, consider using [`tf.scatter_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd) or other ways to build your tensor. It's a very common mistake to use variables to build temporal tensors, because sometimes it's easier, but they are not meant for that.

Comment: If you do want to keep the variable value, though, you should still build the tensor value in graph (without the variable), use it to compute the gradients, and then assign its value to the variable.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I think this would work. All I need is a scatter operation with unity gradient. Thanks!